# How to select all records greater than a date in mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sql

**My table:** (`validfrom` and `validto` and `03JUL2014` below all are of type `DATE`, not `STRING`)

```
id   type    validfrom    validto 
-------------------------------------
1   "APPLE"   10MAY2011    15APR2012
1   "APPLE"   19APR2012    15APR2017
1   "ORANGE"   10MAY2011    15APR2012
1   "ORANGE"   19APR2012    15AUG2018
1   "PEAR"   10MAY2012    15APR2013
1   "PEAR"   10MAY2011    15APR2018
2   "APPLE"   10MAY2011    15APR2017
2   "APPLE"   10MAY2011    15APR2012
2   "ORANGE"   10MAY2011    15APR2012
2   "ORANGE"   10MAY2011    15APR2015
2   "ORANGE"   10MAY2007    15APR2019
2   "PEAR"   10MAY2003    15APR2012
2   "PEAR"   10MAY2006    15APR2022
```

I want to retrieve all records where `id` is `2` and `validto` is greater than `03JUL2014`.

Thus I must get:

```
2   "APPLE"   10MAY2011    15APR2017
2   "ORANGE"   10MAY2007    15APR2019
2   "PEAR"   10MAY2006    15APR2022
```

I tried:

```
SELECT type, validfrom, MAX(validto) FROM crew_qualifications 
               WHERE id=2 AND validto >= 03JUL2014
```

It only gave me:

```
2   "PEAR"   10MAY2006    15APR2022
```

Comment: What is data type of `valid_from` and `valid_to` ?

Comment: why you dont save the date in common datetime format

Comment: valid_from and valid_to are DATEs.

Comment: alwbtc: The formatting of your date columns is causing the confusion among respondents.  I'd suggest you remove the MAX() operator around valid_to, as Appasaheb, below, as suggested (assuming that validto, shown here, is a typo as well).

Answer (score 2):

In your query you write  MAX(validto)  then it return only those row which has validto value is max

you remove MAX(validto) then it return the proper ans

Comment: But I want to get the record whose validto is greater than 03JUL2014, and amongst those, I want to get the one with max validto date

Answer (score 0):

First find the maximum date per type in the given time range. Then join with your table again to get the complete record.

```
select cq.type, cq.validfrom, cq.validto
from crew_qualifications cq
join
(
  select type, max(validto) as validto
  from crew_qualifications 
  where validto >= '2014-07-03'
  group by type
) wanted_cq
on wanted_cq.type = cq.type and wanted_cq.validto = cq.validto;
```

As to your query: You select MAX(validto) without groups, so you get the MAX(validto) for the whole table, i.e. one record. Along with the MAX(validto) you get a random type and a random validfrom from your table, as you don't specify which type and validfrom you want to see (the minimum, maximum, or the average). (Besides `validto >= 03JUL2014` should give you a syntax error. I'm surprised it obviously doesn't. I don't know, how MySQL interprets this here.)